# Wordpress, how to figure out how to edit front page

Tags: frontpage

I am currently using the Onepress theme and want to edit the header section, the part that prints the site title. However, I cannot for the love of life figure out which part actually controls the header. Header.php does not show anything and neither does the frontpage template.

Comment: Hello @QuyNguyen2013 - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! While header-related code often resides in a theme's `header.php` or `index.php` files, this is not always the case - and without knowing with the specific theme, your question is difficult for our community members to answer. For this reason, questions regarding 3rd-party plugins and themes are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. You can try to rephrase your question in a more general format, but it would probably be best addressed in the 3rd-party's official support channels.

Comment: @bosco So is there no general way to figure out where the header is?

Comment: Not really... generally it's self evident. The vast majority of themes just use the [`get_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) function in `index.php` (and/or another [top-level template](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)) to load `header.php` or `header-{something}.php`. If the theme uses it's own loading logic however - then you'll probably have to dig or ask the author. You could try to search for the functions that print the site title in the theme directory, I guess .Usually `get_bloginfo()` or `bloginfo()`.

Comment: I took a look at the theme. You'll want to check out the `onepress_site_header()` and `onepress_site_logo()` functions in `inc/template-tags.php`. The hint was that the theme is using `do_action()` calls where the site header should be - searching for the action tags in the theme revealed the `add_action()` calls that execute functions there. Instead of editing the functions, you could alternately use the [Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to detach those action hooks and add your own functions in their place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WP, you first need to understand the template hierarchy
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

So as per hierarchy,

-- front-page.php

-- home.php / custom page template.

If you have front-page.php , then please check which header file it is enqueuing.

If there is no front-page.php then check home.php exist in your theme file. If yes check which header file it is enqueuing .

If it doesn't have both file, goto Appearance >> Customise >> Static Front Page.

[image]

So if it has some template name in Front Page then you need to check in your template file for which header file it is adding.

#### Header File

For header file, if they are using get_header(), then it will use header.php from your active theme.

If it has get_header( 'home' ); then it will use header-home.php

So from there you can go customise your header.

Also if you are using child theme , then please make check if it has header related file in your child theme or not.

Thanks